# Adding custom customer attribute to admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminform, customer-attribute

I am creating a module that will prevent the user from logging in until the admin has approved the account. I have added a custom attribute using the below install script:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Is Active',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'default' => '0',
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'used_in_forms' => array(
        'adminhtml_customer',
    ),
    'comment' => 'Flag to check if user can log into their account. 0 = No, 1 = Yes.',
); 

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'can_log_in', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

The account listener works and the attribute is being set (I can see it in the database). The problem is, I cannot see it in the admin area (Customers -> Manage Customers -> Edit -> Account Information) to toggle.

How do I get my attribute to appear in the Account Information segment of the edit customer form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Is Active',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'default' => '0',
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'used_in_forms' => array(
        'adminhtml_customer',
    ),
    'comment' => 'Flag to check if user can log into their account. 0 = No, 1 = Yes.',
); 

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'can_log_in', $attribute);

 Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'can_log_in')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'))
    ->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

if you want to add it in all the place use below

```
 Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getAttribute('customer', 'can_log_in')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','checkout_register'))
    ->save();
```

Comment: This has worked. I am only interested in letting the Admin see/edit this value. Why does this work, and what I did not?

Comment: if you check the entity table in database called "customer_form_attribute
" you will find different form_codes. These are referring to different form attributes and for the latest magento you must require to add attribute to different form codes

Comment: In my attribute array I have `used_in_forms` and set `adminhtml_customer`. Why did that not save? Why do we need to use the `eav/config` to set the data?

Comment: Check my answer i had faced same problem when am working on it.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King I encountered the same problem last year and only just worked it out. `used_in_forms` is not specified in `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup::_prepareValues` and so cannot work in `addAttribute` method, it must be added afterwards and then saved again.

Answer (score 2):

Try bellow script

```
<?php
$installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$entityTypeId     = (int)$installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = (int)$installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = (int)$installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'can_log_in', array(
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'Is Active',
    'forms'         => array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'),
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined'  => 1,
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, 'can_log_in', 100);

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'can_log_in');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'));
$oAttribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

custom attribute don't save value in database until you use system => 0; attribute in addAttribute() method.

#### Example:

> $installer->addAttribute('customer', 'can_log_in', array(
> system => 0;
> ));